# Whenever I use send_mail in django it sends me emails from myself rather than the address I'm providing

Tags: python, django, email, sendmail

So I've been working on this blog website and I wanted to add a form so that users can contact the blog admin. However when they fill out the form and send email.. The email I receive is from myself and not from the user. Someone Please help me to fix it.
The form is working correctly and message-email does return the email that they enter.

e.g. lets say in my form I add a user email as example1@example.com
but when I recieve an email it's not coming from example1@example.com but from my host email myemail@gmail.com.

```
views.py:
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message_name = request.POST['message-name']
        message_email = request.POST['message-email']
        message = request.POST['message']

        #send mail
        send_mail(
            'message from ' + message_name + ' their email ' + message_email ,
            message, 
            message_email, 
            ['myemail@gmail.com'],
        )

        return render(request, 'blog/contact.html', {'message_name':message_name})

settings.py:
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_POST = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Google does that. You can't choose the sender with them.

Comment: @KlausD. so is there no way to receive emails from someone else?

Comment: Of cause there is such a way: use an other email service!

Answer (score 0):

This may have some useful information.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server

> Note: Google will automatically rewrite the From line of any email you
> send via its SMTP server to the default email address associated with
> the account if the one used is not on the Send mail as addresses list
> in Gmail or G Suite settings. You can verify the list by going to the
> Accounts and Import tab on the settings screen.
>
> You need to be aware of this nuance because it affects the
> presentation of your email, from the point of view of the recipient,
> and it may also affect the Reply To setting of some programs.

Comment: Yes i think i understand how google stmp service works. Still can't figure out how to program the website somehow so that I receive it from the proper person but ig i have to do without it. This article did educate me so thanks!